# C efficient way to read a file of 20000000 lines

Tags: c, file-io, malloc, generic-programming

I'm trying to read a huge dataset of 20 millions lines, in each line there is a huge number (in fact I'm storing the number in `unsigned long long` variables), for example: `1774251443, 8453058335, 19672843924`, and so on...

I develop a simple function to do this, I'll show below

```
void read(char pathToDataset[], void **arrayToFill, int arrayLength) {
    FILE *dataset = fopen(pathToDataset, "r");
    if (dataset == NULL ) {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(0); // exit failure, it closes the program
    }

    int i = 0;

    /* Prof. suggestion: do a  malloc RIGHT HERE, for allocate a 
     * space in memory in which store the element
     * to insert in the array
     */

    while (i < arrayLength && fscanf(dataset, "%llu", (unsigned long long *)&arrayToFill[i]) != EOF) {

        // ONLY FOR DEBUG, it will print 
        //printf("line: %d.\n", i);  20ML of lines!

        /* Prof. suggestion: do another malloc here, 
         * for each element to be read. 
         */

        i++;
    }

    printf("Read %d lines", i);
    fclose(dataset);
}
```

the parameter `arrayToFill` is of type `void**` because of the exercise goal. Every function has to perform on generic type, and the array could potentially be filled with every type of data (in this example, huge numbers, but it could contain huge strings, integers and so on...).

**I don't understand why I have to do 2 `malloc` calls, isn't a single one enough?**

Comment: I don't understand either.

Comment: Notice however that `!= EOF` is not correct. You must test `!= 1` - if the file is corrupted, then you wouldn't notice otherwise...

Comment: Do you know how big the array should be before you start?

Comment: I think he meant to do 2000001 mallocs, not 2. One for `*arrayToFill = malloc(200000 * sizeof(char*));` and the other 200000 mallocs for each line read.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you're right! I'll correct it immidiately!

Comment: @KamilCuk Ok, now I understand better! Thank you!

Comment: *sorry it should say `== 1` because it was for positive cases.

Comment: But you're *not* storing strings, but unsigned long long integers.

Comment: When you create the file, are you printing the numbers out as strings? Or are you storing them in binary format in the file? Also note that you probably *cannot* name your function `read()`

Comment: Each separate memory allocation has some overhead associated with it — often 8 or 16 bytes.  20 million separate allocations of 8 bytes (for `sizeof(unsigned long)`) will waste (use) a lot of memory on overhead.  When you're dealing with fixed size units (not variable length character strings), you'd probably do better allocating an array and reallocating periodically, making sure you don't add one unit of memory on each iteration.  Keep track of the size of the array and the number of elements used separately.  When you need more space, double the size of the array.

Comment: Also, efficiency and 20 million line text file of of unsigned long longs in decimal format really do not go into the same sentence...

Comment: @torstenvl on the contrary, it should be perfectly fine to call the function `read`. But not `fread`. If it weren't, no one could ever make a C compiler for any POSIX platform :D

Comment: Thank you guys! You all helped me a lot!

Comment: If you need to have an array pointing to each line, and need to hold all lines in memory, the absolute simplest and lowest-memory overhead is: (1) allocate a buffer that holds entire file contents and read file into it; (2) pass through buffer once to turn newlines into null-terminators, while counting lines; (3) allocate array of pointers or buffer indices for your lines; (4) second pass through buffer to populate line pointers/indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, think of `malloc` as a call for memory to store a number of N objects, all of which are size S.  When you have the parameters `void ** arrayToFill, int arrayLength`, you are saying this array will contain `arrayLength` *amount of* pointers of the size `sizeof(void*)`. That is the first allocation and call to malloc.

But the *members* of that array are pointers, which are meant to hold arrays or essentially memory of some other object themselves. The first call to malloc only allocates memory to store the `void*` of each array member, but the memory for each individual member of the array needs it's own `malloc()` call.

**Efficient Line Reading**

For your other question, making lots of small allocations of memory, and then later on freeing them (assuming you would do so, otherwise you would leak a lot of memory), is very slow. However, the performance hit for I/O related tasks is more based on the number of calls than it is for the *amount* of memory you are allocating.

Have your program read the entire file into memory, and allocate an array of `unsigned long long` for 20 million, or however many integers you expect to handle. This way, you can parse through the file contents, use `strtol` function from `<stdlib.h>`, and one by one copy the resulting long to your large array.

This way, you only use a 2-3 large memory allocations and deallocations.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this POSIX solution, see if it helps

```
#include <unistd.h> //for read, write, lseek
#include <stdio.h> //fprintf
#include <fcntl.h> //for open
#include <string.h> //
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit and define
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int fd; // file descriptor
  char * buffer; //pointer for the malloc

  if(argc < 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Insert the file name as parameter\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

if((fd =  open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)// opens the file in read-only mode
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


off_t bytes = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END); // looks at how many bytes the file has
              lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET); // returns the file pointer to the start position

buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*bytes); // allocates enough memory for reading the file

int r = read(fd, buffer, bytes); //reads the file

if(r == -1)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "Error reading\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fprintf(stdout, "\n%s", buffer); // prints the file

close(fd);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: The memory used here is the size of the text file.  OP's lines of text like `19672843924\n"` would need 12 bytes (or 2 to 21 given `"0\n"` to `"18446744073709551615\n"`) vs 8 when saved as an `unsigned long long`.  This efficiency may/may not  be significant for OP.

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition,  so scaling allocations by it adds nothing but confusion.